# Solarized colorscheme for vim and incorrect background color

Tags: vim, rxvt

I use [urxvt](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html) with the [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) light color palette. My `.Xresources` file is properly configured according to [these instructions](https://github.com/solarized/xresources). I also use Vim as my main editor. I've installed the Solarized colorscheme for Vim and modified my `.vimrc` file according to [these instructions](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized). I like the light background color, so I put the following lines in `.vimrc`

```
syntax enable
set background=light
colorscheme solarized
```

However, Vim set the background color to dark. Then I edited the second line, wrote `set background=dark` and vim changed the background color to light.

The problem is that `set background=light` gives me the dark background and `set background=dark` gives me the light background. Why this weird behavior? How to fix this problem? Ah, if I leave out the `set background` line, everything looks fine (the background is light). I've also noticed that gvim sets the correct background color.

Comment: your configured terminal has solarized light color too?

Comment: Yes, I use urxvt with the Solarized light color palette.

Comment: my terminal is urxvt too. I had used solarized colorscheme (dark) for about 1 day, then used a customized scheme. You could try my old config: add these two lines in your vimrc (before colorscheme cmd) , and try: `let g:solarized_termcolors = 256` and `let g:solarized_termtrans = 1` if it worked, I post it as answer.

Comment: I put these two lines in vimrc and the colors don't look nice anymore. The problem is that `set background=light` gives me the dark background and `set background=dark` gives me the light background.

Comment: By the way, gvim sets the correct background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found what's going wrong. The official (?) [Solarized for X Windows](https://github.com/solarized/xresources) is broken when using light colors. There's a discussion [here](https://github.com/solarized/xresources/pull/4) and [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/1lv73i/help_solarized_on_terminal_using_inverted_colors/). The color scheme didn't adjust to the value of `background`. I solved the problem using [the config from seletskiy](https://github.com/solarized/xresources/pull/6) configuration.